# Flash AS3 - 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, movieclip

I asked a question the other day and it taught me a fair bit about display objects and stuff. I have another problem though.

This is my document class :

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Engine extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Engine()
        {
            var calling:Callitems = new Callitems(cat, BluKnife)

            stage.addChild(calling);

        }

    }

}
```

`cat` and `BluKnife` are movieclips in my library with as3 linkage to those names.

Now here is the `Callitems` Class

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;


    public class Callitems extends MovieClip{


    public function Callitems(Enemy1, Enemy2)
    {
        var knife:Enemy1 = new Enemy1();

        this.addChild(knife);
        knife.x = 200;


        var ct:Enemy2 = new Enemy2();

        this.addChild(ct);


    }

}

}
```

Now my problem is that when I wasn't giving `Callitems` arguments and was instead just making `Enemy1`, `cat` and making `Enemy2`, `Bluknife` both of those movieclips were added to the stage as expected. But now that I'm trying to make `Callitems` take arguments so that I can place different clips at certain times I'm getting the following error:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Enemy1.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Enemy2.

Thanks everyone, any help is much appreciated

Edit: I did search this site for that same error, but I don't understand the problem in this context, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Enemy1` is not recognized by the compiler as a type (since it is a variable name) when you define `var knife:Enemy1`. Try just casting it as a more general type:

```
var knife:MovieClip = new Enemy1() as MovieClip;
```

Comment: You're welcome, but read @mossefetcher's answer as weel. You should also specify a type for your constructor's parameters. And you should also use lower-case variables (knife, type1) and upper-case classes (Cat, BlueKnife).

Comment: Ahh yes, noted. Yeah I tried this solution in conjunction with mossefetcher's but I was getting the same answer. Maybe I was doing it wrong. Do you mean specifying the type as in Enemy:MovieClip? Instead of just letting it use the default 'object' type?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant `public function Callitems(type1:Class, type2:Class)`

Comment: And then `var knife:MovieClip = new type1() as MovieClip`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you seem to have class names as the parameters for the Callitems constructor.
It should read something like:

```
public function Callitems(parameter1:Enemy1, parameter2:Enemy2)
    {...
```

You are also passing undefined variables to the Callitems constructor (cat and BluKnife). If they're supposed to be passed into Callitems (which is, perhaps, not a great idea), they should at least be defined first.

Comment: Thanks also! Sorry I understand what you mean now too, I'll work on using better practices.